# How to show a hidden div by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to hide a `div` if `javascript` is turned off and show that `div` if `javascript` enabled but I don't want to use `<noscript>` as in chrome and opera it has some issues. So what I am doing is something like this:

```
<div id="box" style="display:none"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("box").style.visibility = "visible";
</script>
```

But the javascript part does not show the div. How can I make it visible is javascript is enabled. Also tried `$('#box').show();` but that too didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `style.display`

```
document.getElementById("box").style.display = "block";
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the attribute `display` to `block`

`document.getElementById("box").style.display = "block";`

You are trying to toggle between visibility, which is similar, but a different property.

Answer (score 1):

You are using display: none, not visibility: hidden.
Solution add    visibility: hidden instead of display none if you want to use that instead of display. They work a little different.

Answer (score 1):

You can set:

```
<div id='box' style='display: none;'>...</div>
```

And in your script code:

```
document.getElementById('box').style.display = 'block';
```

Answer (score 1):

change display to visibility

```
<div id="box" style="visibility:none"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("box").style.visibility = "visible";
</script>
```

or change js

```
<div id="box" style="display:none"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         document.getElementById("box").style.display = "block";
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a mix of CSS and Javascript to accomplish this:

## HTML/Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.documentElement.className += 'js-ready';
</script>
```

## CSS

```
div#box { display: none; }
.js-ready div#box { display: block !important; }
```